# Solve double integral $\iint_E\frac{1 + x}{1 + 2x^2 + 3y^2} dA$ ellipstic area $E$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, elliptic-equations

I am trying to solve the integral

$$\iint_E\frac{1 + x}{1 + 2x^2 + 3y^2} dA$$

where E is the elliptical area given by $$2x^2 + 3y^2\leq 6$$

I have tried substitution with $(x, y)\mapsto(\sqrt{3} r\cos\theta, \sqrt{2}r\sin\theta)$, where the new ranges are $r\in [0, 1]$ and $\theta\in [0, 2\pi]$. Then I substitute that into the integral and solve it with the new limits.

Is this the right way to go? I get an answer of $\pi\ln 7$ and that seems a bit weird but I am pretty unsure. Can someone guide me in the right direction in this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 6):

Due to symmetry, the integral simplifies

\begin{align}
I= \iint_{E}\frac{1 + x}{1 + 2x^2 + 3y^2} dxdy
= \iint_{E}\frac{1}{1 + 2x^2 + 3y^2} dx d y
\end{align}
Then, with $x=\sqrt3 u$ and $y=\sqrt2 v$
\begin{align}
I
&= \iint_{2x^2 + 3y^2\leq 6}\frac{1}{1 + 2x^2 + 3y^2} dx d y\\
& =\sqrt6 \iint_{u^2+v^2\leq 1}\frac{1}{1 + 6(u^2 + v^2)} du d v\\
 & =2\pi \sqrt6 \int_0^1\frac{r}{1 + 6r^2} dr
= \frac{\pi \ln7}{\sqrt6}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain a little bit the simplification?

Comment: @user56202 - $x$ in the numerator is odd with respect to the elliptical area and vanishes upon integration

Comment: Ohh that is clever, thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Quanto. How it is possible to see these kinds of symmetries? I am still a bit lost in finding these simplifications.

Comment: Also, how does the sqrt(6) come in the denominator? Shouldn't it be sqrt(6) * pi * ln 7?

Comment: @dacritical - For a symmetric area such as an ellipse, integration on any odd part of an integrand vanishes. The $r$ integration produces a factor of 12 in the denominator.